# Добавить слушателя к div в цикле

Tags: javascript

Хочу отобразить онлайн,оффлайн пользователей чата и приписать определенную логику при нажатии на одного из такого пользователя(div).
Есть JSONArray,читаю циклом по очереди JSONObject вот таким образом :

```
socket.onmessage = function(evt){
var json = JSON.parse(evt.data);
var online = json.Online;
var offline = json.Offline;
    for(var i = 0 ; i < online.length ; i++){
        var current = online[i];

        var div = document.createElement("div");
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.innerHTML = current.login;
        div.appendChild(p);
        document.getElementById("People").appendChild(div);

        div.addEventListener("click" , dialog(div));

    }
}   

function dialog(div){
    alert("I am here");
    div.style.background = "blue";
    div.style.height = "50px";
    div.style.width = "100px";
}
```

Хочу,чтобы при нажатии на один из div,срабатывала функция dialog и в нее передавался этот div,на который было нажатие.

Вся проблема в том,что у меня срабатывает слушатель без моего нажатия.Когда я прогрузил страницу и JSONArray пришел,у меня срабатывает dialog() и я вижу alert.

Comment: Потому что ты сразу вызываешь метод `dialog(div)`, а надо ссылку на функуию передавать и потом через запятую параметр. В доках есть варианты https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div.addEventListener("click" , dialog);
...

function dialog(){
    alert("I am here");
    this.style.background = "blue";
    this.style.height = "50px";
    this.style.width = "100px";
}
```